# update table from chilled table with group by in oracle

Tags: oracle

i have two tables master and other is child. suddenly i have lost voucher_date in master table. now how can i update it from child table where many record inserted against one voucher_number.
i have tried the query

```
update salem set (vch_date,vch_temp)=(
     SELECT 
    vch_date,
    vch_no  
FROM sale where salem.vch_no=sale.vch_no GROUP BY vch_no,vch_date);
```

but i got message

> SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
>   01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Regard.

Comment: For a given `vch_no`  are the values of `(vch_date, vch_no)`  always the same in the `sale`  table? If not, which values do you want to write to the master table?

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP BY` you used is, actually, `DISTINCT` applied to selected column list. It appears that - for a certain `vch_no` which establishes relation between those two tables - you don't have a distinct `vch_date + vch_no` combination, which also means that there are several `vch_date` values for each `vch_no`. What to do? Pick one, for example maximum.

Also, you're setting `salem.vch_temp` to `sale.vch_no` which is pointless as `vch_no` from `sale` is equal to `vch_no` from `salem` so you can set `salem.vch_temp` to `salem.vch_no`.

```
UPDATE salem m SET 
  m.vch_date = (SELECT MAX(s.vch_date)
                FROM sale s
                WHERE m.vch_no = s.vch_no 
               ),
  m.vch_temp = m.vch_no;
```